# Парсинг файла плейлиста m3u8 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Ребята, всем привет. Есть плейлист IPTV в формате .m3u8. Но телевизор, вернее OTT-player не полностью понимает содержимое плейлиста. Исходный плейлист имеет вид:

```
#EXTINF:0 group-title="Эфирные HD",Первый канал HD
https://megogo.cdnvideo.ru/1tvstream/playlist.m3u8
```

плюс еще 1000 таких строк.
А нужно из него сделать такое:

```
#EXTINF:0,Первый канал HD
#EXTGRP:Эфирные HD
https://megogo.cdnvideo.ru/1tvstream/playlist.m3u8
```

Регулярки не втыкаю пока. Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(r'D:\temp\playlist.m3u8')    
data = p.read_text(encoding='utf-8')

pat = r'(#EXTINF:[^\s+])\s+group-title=\"([^"]*)\",(.*)'

out = Path(r'D:\temp\playlist_new.m3u8')
out.write_text(re.sub(pat, r'\1,\3\n#EXTGRP:\2', data))
```

Исходный файл:

```
#EXTINF:0 group-title="Эфирные HD1",Первый канал HD
https://megogo.cdnvideo.ru/1tvstream/playlist.m3u8
#EXTINF:1 group-title="Эфирные HD2",Второй канал HD
https://megogo.cdnvideo.ru/2tvstream/playlist.m3u8
```

результат:

```
#EXTINF:0,Первый канал HD
#EXTGRP:Эфирные HD1
https://megogo.cdnvideo.ru/1tvstream/playlist.m3u8
#EXTINF:1,Второй канал HD
#EXTGRP:Эфирные HD2
https://megogo.cdnvideo.ru/2tvstream/playlist.m3u8
```

Comment: Все четко получилось. Спасибо